# How to replace/delete a certain symbol in a png/jpg/jpeg image in ffmpeg?

Tags: image, ffmpeg

Given a png image, suppose I want to delete a certain symbol(such as # or the letter t...) all appear in the image.(suppose I have had the explicit image of # and t as pdf file)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikHOl.png)
Notice that what I wanted to edit is an image, not text...
Is there some way to do it(such as delete all the # appears in the image with empty background)?
I don't want to edit each #(or each t) one by one...

Comment: pay attention I may have mutiple fonts, I only want to change all the t, bu not change such as bold t. I hope there exists a quick way to do this

Comment: more example: substitute ￡with $ in am image